# Add ng-model value in false condition of ng-attr-title

Tags: angularjs

How to do I add `mainCtrl.header.Version` in the string text if the condition in `ng-attr-title` is false?

**HTML**

```
<label class="form-control" ng-attr-title="{{mainCtrl.header.Version == 0 ? 'This form has not yet been submitted for approval' : 'This form has been submitted for approval {{mainCtrl.header.Version}} times'}}">{{mainCtrl.header.Version}}</label>
```

Comment: `<label ng-if="mainCtrl.header.Version == 0">This form has not yet been submitted for approval</label>` `<label ng-if="mainCtrl.header.Version != 0">This form has been submitted for approval {{mainCtrl.header.Version}} times</label>`

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Thanks for your suggested solution. Is it possible with just using ng-attr-title?

Comment: `ng-attr-title="{{mainCtrl.header.Version == 0 ? 'This form has not yet been submitted for approval' : 'This form has been submitted for approval ' + mainCtrl.header.Version + ' times'}}"` should work

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant I tried this before but it didn't work. I tried it again just now and it worked! I must have missed something. Can you submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is :

```
ng-attr-title="{{mainCtrl.header.Version == 0 ? 'This form has not yet been submitted for approval' : 'This form has been submitted for approval ' + mainCtrl.header.Version + ' times'}}"
```

ng-attr-title displays the string it is given, so you have to use {{ expr }}.
To test your expression I'd advice you to write `<pre>{{ your expression | json }}</pre>` to see what is the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it from JS controller side. Take a variable `title` check if `version` is 0 then assign title you want. And if version is > than 0 then concat the version with title message. Please consider the following code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as mainCtrl">
<label class="form-control" ng-attr-title="{{mainCtrl.title}}">
{{mainCtrl.header.Version}} 
</label>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    var mainCtrl = this;
    mainCtrl.header = {"Version":0};
    if( mainCtrl.header.Version == 0 )
    {
     mainCtrl.title = "This form has not yet been submitted for approval";
    }
    else
    {
     mainCtrl.title = "This form has not yet been submitted for " +mainCtrl.header.Version+"  approval";
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by calling a function like that:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('htmlTitle', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
  
  $scope.mainCtrl = {
        header: {
         Version: 0
        }
    };
  
  $scope.get_title = function(){
    if($scope.mainCtrl.header.Version == 0){
      return 'This form has not yet been submitted for approval';
    }
    else{
      return 'This form has been submitted for approval ' +  $scope.mainCtrl.header.Version + ' times';
    }
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="htmlTitle">
    
    <label class="form-control"  title="{{get_title()}}" >{{mainCtrl.header.Version}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/moahammadalt/pen/exvrpe?editors=1010).